# Python code to retrieve csv file and display in terminal

Tags: python, csv, authentication, url, proxy

I am recieving syntax errors in the below code on line 23 when trying to download and display csv file on linux. I removed the authentication details for privacy reasons:

```
import csv
import urllib.request


# URL of the CSV file
url = 'http://165.143.226.108/groups/IPNET-Localpeering/topN/IPNET-Localpeering/IPNET-Localpeering.csv'



# Proxy server details


# Create a password manager and add the username and password
password_mgr = urllib.request.HTTPPasswordMgrWithDefaultRealm()
password_mgr.add_password(None, url, username, password)

# Create an authentication handler for the proxy server
proxy_auth_handler = urllib.request.HTTPBasicAuthHandler()
proxy_auth_handler.add_password('realm', f'http://{proxy_server}:{proxy_port}',
                                proxy_username, proxy_password)

# Create a proxy handler and opener
proxy_handler = urllib.request.ProxyHandler({'http': f'http://{proxy_server}:{proxy_port}',
                                             'https': f'https://{proxy_server}:{proxy_port}'})
opener = urllib.request.build_opener(proxy_handler, proxy_auth_handler, urllib.request.HTTPHandler)

# Install the opener
urllib.request.install_opener(opener)

# Download the CSV file from the URL
response = urllib.request.urlopen(url)
data = response.read().decode('utf-8')

# Parse the CSV data
csv_data = csv.reader(data.splitlines())

# Print each row of the CSV file
for row in csv_data:
    print(row)
```

Comment: Please, post the full traceback you get

Comment: csv.reader(...) expects a "file-like object", you cannot directly pass it a string, you'll need something like `reader = csv.reader(io.StringIO(data))`. Also, you don't need to call splitlines(), the csv reader will figure all that out for itself. And, if you haven't already, please check out the docs on the csv module to make sure you understand the concepts/patterns, https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#module-contents. An example for reader is at that link.

Comment: @Gius, OP needs to figure out how manage strings and files. Pandas, as you've suggested, doesn't solve anything here.